# How to trigger apt update after package install?

Tags: apt, package-management, updates

I created an apt-source package which add a couple of repository to the system and the corresponding GPG keys to APT keychain.

How can I automatically trigger `apt update` after this package is installed or updated?

I guess I cannot call `apt update` directly from post install script as APT is busy configuring packages. What is the best way to do this, in the same way as the apt-add-repository command?

Comment: One-line them together?  `sudo add-apt-repository [...] && sudo apt-get update` would probably do it (replace the `[...]` with the actual arguments though)

Comment: @ThomasWard in the package I don't directly trigger apt-add-repository, I manually place files /etc/apt.
I want to keep using a package so I can deploy/update repositories on all computers at once.

Comment: Ah.  That's typically *not* the best way to do things though, but you SHOULD be able to call `apt update` afterwards.  The problem is that the types of behavior you're looking for are not typically "package level" commands/behavior, those're usually *scripts* behavior, because of the way `dpkg` and `apt` locks things